# about nop3.3 redis cache

Tags: redis, nopcommerce

I wrote a cache extension code below

```
public class RedisManager:ICacheManager
    {
        private readonly RedisClient _client;
        public RedisManager()
        {
            _client = new RedisClient("127.0.0.1", 6379);
        }
        public T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            return _client.Get<T>(key);
        }

        public void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime)
        {
            _client.Add(key, data);
        }

        public bool IsSet(string key)
        {
            return _client.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        public void Remove(string key)
        {
            _client.Remove(key);
        }

        public void RemoveByPattern(string pattern)
        {
            _client.RemoveByPattern(pattern);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _client.FlushDb();
        }
    }
```

Then modify the configuration

```
builder.RegisterType<RedisManager>().As<ICacheManager>().Named<ICacheManager>("nop_redis_cache_static").SingleInstance();
```

But after running a mistake, the error is：

> Unhandled exception "System.StackOverflowException" type of place in
>   System.Web.dll

How can we solve?